# Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge issues syntax error but the same code will not get any syntax error when checking syntax from Progress Editor

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, webspeed

PDSOE version 4.5.2, OE 11.7.1 - 64-bit - Win 10 64

I have an Webspeed (.w) opened in my PSDOE.
If I simply right click over this code and choose Check Syntax in the context menu (Ctrl+Shift+C)
it will return me an error from an include file used by this .w regarding the get-cookie():

Syntax Check:
** Unable to understand after -- "GET-COOKIE". (247)

In my .w, I have all the necessary Webspeed include files - including proto.i that will have the forward get-cookie function signature and all that.

So far so good, I could have thought of Propath and all that, but two things make things more complicated now:

1. If I choose to compile the code instead of checking syntax, it will compile just fine - which tells me that all my include files and propath are correctly configured and all set, a .r is produced
2. If from PDSOE, with my code still opened, I go in Eclipse \ OpenEdge \ Tool \ Procedure Editor , it will open a Progress Editor with the same code in place right, and from this procedure editor, if I simply right click and check syntax, it will return no errors at all.

I downloaded OE 12.3 and tried the same thing, got the same behavior.
I checked all the propath and it was right (code compiles)
I tried restarting the AVM, no difference
I tried a shared AVM, no difference

I am running out of ideas specially after I got the same issue on 12.3.

Would you happen to have any other idea or could thing of anything else that could explain the check syntax behavior in PDSOE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So your project configuration sounds o.k.. You should open a call with Progress tech support IMHO.

If your .w file is a mapped web object and not a CGI wrapper, you might have little luck with support for those on OpenEdge 12.3 - as PASOE does not support running them. There's an enhancement request open for votes: https://openedge.ideas.aha.io/ideas/OPENEDGE-I-753?utm_source=idea_comment_mailer&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=subscribers

On OpenEdge 11.7.1 this should still be supported though.

CGI wrappers should work fine on OpenEdge 12.3 though.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks Mike, This is a classic webspeed architecture. This is a mapped web-object. But again, it complies fine from the same PDSOE editor when after right-clicking in the source code I select "compile" instead of "check syntax", so, I believe the same AVM that is responsible to compile the code and produce the .r is responsible to check syntax when asked. The same preprocessors and include files that are available in the code when I ask to compile it are resolved the same way in order and priority as to when I ask to check syntax only, from Proc Editor from pdsoe syntax will check fine, weird

Comment: I believe that - from PDSOE - having a file opened in an editor, when you go to the menu \ OpenEdge \ Tools \ Procedure Editor, a new Progress client will be started to take care of that and will carry all the configurations (propath, DLC, promsgs, codepage, etc) and from there the same code will be copied (opened) and resolved the same way in terms of preprocessors/include files and will check syntax fine. That must be a bug within PDSOE thats been there for some time now all the way up to 12.3. Thanks!

Comment: When you open the procedure editor in PDSOE, it's using the Project AVM - so it is _not_ starting a new AVM. Honestly, I think your case is a case for Progress tech support. Challenge may be however, that mapped web objects are not supported in PASOE and PASOE is the only WebSpeed in OE12. So that makes mapped web objects most likely unsupported today.  So you should open a suppoer case on OpenEdge 11.7. FYI 11.7.9 was released yesterday.